# Is the PLSQL Function result cache a Enterprise edition feature still in Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Can someone help me to find whether the PL/SQL function cache feature is still an enterprise edition feature when it comes to ORACLE 19c?
I know that it is an enterprise edition feature when it was introduced back in 2007 in ORACLE 11g, But I couldn't find the new categorization of this feature in ORACLE 19c.

Answer (score 1):

When I google furthermore I could find the feature list page for ORACLE 19c with the availability of each feature for each edition.

**It is still an Enterprise Edition feature**

[image]

If you want you can check other features as well from the below link to Oracle 19c documentation.

[Oracle 19c feature availability in each edition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87)